# If $a_n \to 0^-$ . Why does $\frac{1}{a_n} \to -\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $a_n \to 0^-$ . Why does $\frac{1}{a_n} \to -\infty$ ?

I know that $\frac{1}{0} = \infty$ , of course, but why does a sequence tending to $0$ from the negative mean that the inverse tends to negative infintiy? why Negative?

Comment: The intuition behind this is that, if $x$ is a small negative number, then its inverse is a large negative number. For example $\frac{1}{-0.001} = -1000$.

Comment: Because all the $a_n$ are negative and thus $\dfrac {1}{a_n}$ is a negative quantity.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to plot the graph of $1/x$ and ''see where the $x$ goes'' as it approaches zero from the left.

Comment: It might be correct to write $|1/0|=\infty$, but $1/0=\infty$ (without the absolute value signs) is meaningful only in the loosest sense of the infinity symbol. In general, "$\infty$" is shorthand for a statement about limits.

Comment: But to be precise, there is no nuber $0^-$ as there is no number $- \infty$. To write $a_n \to 0^-$ is a simple notation to mean that $\{ a_n \}$ is a succession of negative numbers having $0$ as limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$a_n\to0^-\implies a_n<0$$
Hence,
$$\frac{1}{a_n}<0$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{a_n}\to-\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cne7wuioah, particularly between $x=-1$ and $x=0$. You'll see the curve sloping down towards $-\infty$, just as it tends to $+\infty$ when $x$ tends to $0$ from the positive direction

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{1}{0} = \infty$

Actually, most mathematicians would not say that.  They would just say that is undefined.

Read the definition of $\to -\infty$ carefully. It does not actually involve infinity at all.  It says that the sequence will be less that any negative value if you go beyond a certain point.  So, it will be less than negative million if you are beyond a suitable point, it will be less than negative billion beyond another suitable point, less than negative googolplex, etc.  Saying "tends to negative infinity" is just a suggestive name.

A simple sequence that $\to -\infty$ is $-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, . . .$  It clearly satisfies the definition.  It will be less than $-N$ after the $N$th term.  No actual infinity (in any of its many senses) is involved.

Answer (score 0):

> Lets try $x≈0.000000001$ and $x≈-0.000000001$.

I think, you understood the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

As $a_n$ approaches $0$, with $a_n \ne 0$, we get that $|a_n|$ approaches $0$ from above, so $\left|{\large{\frac{1}{a_n}}}\right|$ approaches infinity.

Hence if $a_n$ approaches $0$ from below, $\left|{\large{\frac{1}{a_n}}}\right|$ approaches infinity, but then, since each of the terms ${\large{\frac{1}{a_n}}}$ is negative, it follows that ${\large{\frac{1}{a_n}}}$ approaches minus infinity.

But note: Your assertion that ${\large{\frac{1}{0}}}=\infty$ is not correct.

A fixed version of that idea would be: ${\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0^+}}} {\large{\frac{1}{x}}}=\infty$.